# .NET Framework 4.0 Alternative to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost

Tags: c#, .net, owin, self-host-webapi

I have an old windows application that runs on .NET Framework 4.0 that now needs to selfhost a web service in order to respond to Web API calls. For that, I tried to setup OwinSelfHost library, but when I try to install through Nuget, I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost ', You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."
```

I tried to install the legacy library, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Selfhost, but I also get the same issue. Is there an alternative library that I can use?

Looking for a short term solution, I'm aware updating the framework would be a better long term solution, but the scope in development, deployment, testing, etc. is not be manageable at this cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [HttpListener class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.5.2). It is what OWIN ultimately uses as well. However, you will have to handle all aspects of the HTTP request and response. You will not get anything like the `ApiController` class, routing, or parameter binding. You should be able to find many examples.